# How to solve cyclic relationship in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I have table for students , instructors and courses.

1. Relationship between instructor and course many to many  (as instructor can teach many course and course can be tough by many instructors )
   I create instructorcourse table to break many to many
2. Relationship between student and course many to many (as student can register in many courses and course have many students)
   I create studentcourse table to break many to many
3. Relationship between student and instructor one to many 
   So l have a problem in cyclic relationship

Comment: You need additional tables, for example classes...

Comment: So your question is?.

Comment: What problem do you have? I don't see any (yet) .....

Comment: When is your homework assignment due?

Answer (score 0):

You can create cross-relation tables
I mean you can create StudentCourses table for example with StudentId & CourseId fields (as composite primary key if required)